# Duplicate item in another list

Tags: updatelistitems

I have three SharePoint lists: List A, List B, and ListC.
After creating an item in those lists, a workflow starts a task process and the item status changes to “waiting for meeting” and keeps that until the real meeting occur.

I want to create a SharePoint list named “Items to be discussed in the next meeting” and copy all items from ListA, ListB, and ListC that present the status “waiting for meeting” to this new list (items to be discussed in the next meeting). When the item status changes to “approved” It should be automatically deleted from this new list.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow which gets triggered only during the item is edited. Whenever the item is being edited, check the status of the column if it is set as "waiting for meeting", if 'Yes', you may create a new item in the new list using the workflow.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you choose something heavy.

Now if you use a Content Search Web Part. On a page you list all items "to be discussed", when you'll update them no need of changes...

Just my thought.

Comment: Could you add more details about how to list items with the term "to be discussed"? I have tried but the system do not return the item.

Comment: I assume that you work yith enterprise licence (that's mandatory for CSWP. So, create a new page. Add this webpart. and follow this guide: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html

Comment: Does the Content Search Web Part includes the workflow status in the query? I am trying to search for a specific query that is the workflow status and got no results.